# angular js ng-repeat is not working with owl carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on the news update section of my Angular website, where I want to display the latest news updates with owl carousel but ng-repeat displays nothing . json data is displaying in console but not in front.

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="owl-news" ng-controller="newsController" data-ng-init="news()">

    <div class="item" ng-repeat="news in allData">
        <div class="news-1">

          <div class="body">

            <p>{{ news.news}}</p>
            <div class="title">{{news.news_date}}</div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Angular code :

```
app.controller("newsController",function($http,$scope,$log){
 var news=function(){
     $http({
           method:"POST",
           url:"getNews.php",
           dataType:"json"
           }).then(function(data){
               $log.log(data);
               $scope.allData=data;
               },function(data){
                   $log.log("Error has occured!.");
               });
     }; news();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smoki99/rqwz6mno/12/

After doing a lot of tests:

$scope.allData the correct return value. Usually "data" contains an additional data field. I unfortunably not know, what your exact "JSON" return looks like, but it take it from this as source (http://www.dysartpharmacy.com/index.php/site_search/get/news)

So I think you must change your line simply to

```
$scope.allData = data.data;
```

Here my complete example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="newsController">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="news in allData">
    <div class="news-1">
      <div class="body">
        <p>{{ news.news}}</p>
        <div class="title">{{news.news_date}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And JS Code:

```
// the main (app) module
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
app.controller("newsController",function($http,$scope,$log, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){
    var returnData = '[{"news":"news1","news_date":"2017-09-14"},          {"news":"news2","news_date":"2017-09-14"}]';

    var data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
        json: returnData
    });

    var news = function() {
      $http({
            method: "POST",
          url: "/echo/json/",
          datatype: "json",
          data: data
          }, data).then(function (data) {
          debugger;
            $log.log(data);
                $scope.allData = data.data;
            },function(data) {
            $log.log("Error has occured!");
          });
    };       
    news();

});
```

Comment: Thanks to immediate response. Your code is working well but owl carousel create some problems.  it puts all data into one slide. any suggesssion

Comment: If it is this: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html

than maybe you need the divs rearranged and set to the correct "class"